# Linker generates different code (objdump)

Tags: c++, linker, gnu, vxworks

I have a makefile that generates a shared library. Calling make from different shells (VxWorks wrenv and Cygwin) results in different libs. Thy VxWorks version is working the Cygwin version not. The differences are very small and not visible with the `readelf` program.

Using `objdumparm -S *.so` shows the difference at the end of the functions. See the following output.

Example 1: (two last line differ)

Cygwin:

```
00010a14 <_ZN3rag3MD511save_digestEPhPKm>:
10a14:  e1a0c00d    mov ip, sp
10a18:  e92dda30    push    {r4, r5, r9, fp, ip, lr, pc}
...
10b18:  00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
10b1c:  3b6e71a1    blcc    1bad1a8 <_stack+0x1b2d1a8>
10b20:  505c3d7f    subspl  r3, ip, pc, ror sp
```

VxWorks:

```
00010a14 <_ZN3rag3MD511save_digestEPhPKm>:
10a14:  e1a0c00d    mov ip, sp
10a18:  e92dda30    push    {r4, r5, r9, fp, ip, lr, pc}
...
10b18:  00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
10b1c:  00000338    andeq   r0, r0, r8, lsr r3
10b20:  0000033c    andeq   r0, r0, ip, lsr r3
```

or Example 2: (last line differs)

Cygwin:

```
00010b7c <_ZN3rag3MD55beginEv>:
10b7c:  e1a0c00d    mov ip, sp
10b80:  e92dda10    push    {r4, r9, fp, ip, lr, pc}
...
10bd4:  e89daa10    ldm sp, {r4, r9, fp, sp, pc}
10bd8:  00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
10bdc:  695c7960    ldmdbvs ip, {r5, r6, r8, fp, ip, sp, lr}^
```

VxWorks:

```
00010b7c <_ZN3rag3MD55beginEv>:
10b7c:  e1a0c00d    mov ip, sp
10b80:  e92dda10    push    {r4, r9, fp, ip, lr, pc}
...
10bd4:  e89daa10    ldm sp, {r4, r9, fp, sp, pc}
10bd8:  00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
10bdc:  000005ec    andeq   r0, r0, ip, ror #11
```

The parameters for the linker are identical. Do these differences come from the relocation process?

It possible to say why this happens, the reason?

Comment: What are the parameters for the compiler? And btw. what architecture is this? Maybe also the two shells are running in different modes, and this causes the compiler to inherit that mode somehow? (64/32 bit, arm thumb etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, the linker wasn't the bad guy! Found out that the compiler was generating different .sho objects. Using the `-fno-builtin` option to compile the .sho's did remove the differences...